# Visual studio 2017 is not recognizing project of type .sfproj

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to open a solution that I downloaded from a source code for the first time using **Visual Studio 2017**. I got an error:

*This version of visual studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or the … blah blah*.

I figured out that the type of project VS is complaining about is of type **.sfproj**, which I found out is means **Azure Service Fabric **.

I've installed the latest version of Azure Service Fabric **SDK**, as the documentation says, but I'm still getting the error.
Also when I go to **Menu -> file -> New -> Projec**, I don't see any Azure Fabric Service as template.

How to make visual studio recognize the type Azure Service Fabric? Is there more I need to do besides merely installing the SDK?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Go back to the installer and ensure you have the Azure Development workload selected.

Comment: I've uninstalled it. Now I'm trying to install it again, but I don't even see where I should make sure that the Azure Development workload is selected.

Comment: Uninstalling it wasn't necessary.  We can't see what you see.  The available workloads in the installer are [listed here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/selecting-workloads-visual-studio-2017/).  You need the one titled "Azure development".

Comment: Sorry, by installer, I though you were talking about the service fabric one. I've run again the visual studio installer, checked the azure development, and now it working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just to add details to this answer, since it worked for me also. Go to "Apps and Features" by right-clicking on the Windows icon. Then select VisualStudio 2017 and select "Modify", then add Azure Development as the additional workload/developmentArea supported by VisualStudio 2017.

Answer (score 17):

This happens because you haven't installed the Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio.

To setup a development environment to run Service Fabric projects you required 3 things:

1. Service Fabric SDK
2. Service Fabric Runtime (installed with the SDK)
3. Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Depending on the version of your visual studio you will install them in a different way:

For **Visual Studio 2015** you can install all 3 items using the ***Web Platform Installer***. 
Just open the WPI and search for ***Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools v-- (VS2015)***, once the setup is completed just restart the computer and it's all done.

For **Visual Studio 2017** and later, this is process has changed to be 'easier' but is a bit tricky, on VS2017 the Tools are installed with the VS Installer:

- Open Visual Studio
- Tools (On top bar menu)
- Get Tools and Features (the installer will open to modify VS features)
- Azure Development
- select '***Service Fabric***'
- Confirm the changes and setup.

Once completed, you have to go on Web Platform Installer and Setup the SDK, the one that does not contain (VS2015) at the end. After setup is completed, restart the computer and it is done.

In both cases, it will setup the latest version of SF, if you require an older version, you will face some challenges.

The problem with VS2017 approach is that you can't select the version you want, so is very likely you will end-up with the most recent version, forcing you to update the project file.

For VS2015 you can chose the version, first you need to discover the version your project need, for this, open the raw .sfproj file and find the element *'ProjectVersion'*, most of the times you need to upgrade the project version(done automaticaly when you install a newer version of the tools) or down grade the sfproj to open with older tools.

To download the tools installer, go to the Service Fabric [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric) and find the release notes for the version you want and then look for the links to download *'Visual Studio 2015 Tool for Service Fabric'*. This does not work with VS2017.

For more information, please see more details on the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

Comment: It's important to note that merely installing the SDK isn't enough. The SDK is not specific to Visual Studio - it's just the general component. Only installing the Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio will allow you to open the project.