# Service Fabric Application template not available in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I have been using Visual Studio 2017 for some time currently(15.7.4). In the installer I have Azure Development ticked and that includes service fabric tools. When I go to create new project the option Visual C# -> Cloud -> Service Fabric Application is not in the list. I have already installed Microsoft Azure Service Fabric 6.2.283.9494, Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 3.1.283.9494 and Mircosoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for VS 2015.

I have created a service fabric cluster using ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json and can see that running at http://localhost:19080/Explorer/index.html#/

I'm not sure what else I need to do to get this template to appear, I assume something in the VS install but I can't see any other options that I need to add.

EDIT: Even after uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2017 Enterprise using the installer and the Service Fabric SDK, I still don't have the option for the template Cloud -> Service Fabric Application

[image]

Comment: Hm, that should be enough as related to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#install-the-sdk-and-tools

Comment: This seems to be a recognised issue see - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63086/project-template-for-service-fabric-missing-after.html I'm running the suggested diagcab, anyone else experienced this?

Comment: @MartinBrandl I've followed the docs to install, but maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: Is that a typo (VS 2015), or did you install tools for the wrong version of VS?

Comment: It's not a typo, there is no tools for vs2017. It is supposed to be built into the service fabric sdk.

Comment: I've uninstalled to vs2015 tools just in case there was some conflict and this has meant I've had to reinstall the sdk, still don't get the option...

Comment: Do you have such folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Service Fabric Tools"?

Comment: I don't have that folder, but a colleague who has it working doesn't have that folder either...

Comment: After install I get a warning - Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Emulator.Exe,version=2.9.8699.21,chip=x64' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Emulator.Exe;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147467259
    Details
        Return code: -2147467259
        Return code details: Access is denied
I had ignored that previously as I didn't think this would be related - does anyone think it may be?

Comment: Can you see the install logs if there are any other messages? it might be failing as well as the Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Emulator.Exe

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is all down to the Service Fabric SDK not being installed and started properly, but that is another issue. I may close this question and ask a question more specific to that

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you try using the Web Platform Installer to install the sdk, tools and runtime? Open webpi, search for service fabric, install `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 3.1.283`

Comment: Yes, I've installed using the web platform installer and using the direct links. Neither work correctly. Also I have another machine with vs2017 15.34 community which doesn't have the service fabric sdk installed but it does have the option for cloud->service fabric application! It looks like there is an issue with both my VS2017 installation AND the service fabric sdk which I can't resolve...

Answer (score 2):

When you install the SDK, it does not install the Visual Studio Tools.

The SF Tools for VS is a separate installation, the version you installed is specific for VS 2015, for Visual Studio 2017 you have to install it from the ***Visual Studio Installer*** > Azure Development > Select 'Service Fabric' and install it. This will install the required VS templates missing.

A similar question has been answered here: 
[Visual studio 2017 is not recognizing project of type .sfproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702234/visual-studio-2017-is-not-recognizing-project-of-type-sfproj/50768482#50768482)

Comment: See above "In the installer I have Azure Development ticked and that includes service fabric tools." I can't see any other options in there relating to service fabric

Comment: Try Uncheck it to uninstall, restart, Install again and restart. Might have some conflicts with other installs.

Comment: Yes I have done this already, should have mentioned that above

Comment: If you open a sfproj does it open without any warning?

Comment: No, if you open a SF project it is marked as incompatible, if you right click on it you get a migration report - "The application which this project type is based on was not found" and this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh266747.aspx which doesn't say anything about service fabric

Comment: A colleague had a similar problem when he updated VS from 15.5 to 15.7, the solution he found was reinstall VS. If you already tried all options I don't see other option.

Comment: I've now reinstalled. I still don't have the option

Comment: Are you sure that after selecting Azure Development you also checked(if not checked) 'Service Fabric Tools' option in the list of tools on the right?

Comment: Yes, and I've checked and unchecked this option several times and "modified"

Comment: @kayakpim See if a "repair" helps. Visual Studio Installer > Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 > More > Repair.

Comment: I've done both a repair and and a fresh install. It's definitely some kind of permissions issue with the SDK but I can't get to the bottom of it

Comment: The above answer is correct. Merely installing the SDK doesn't solve the problem. You need to also install the Visual Studio tools.